# How to design 1-to-1 self-relation in Prisma?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have pretty simple case with 1-to-1 self-relation. One Person may have one spouse. I have created wife/husband in order to activate relations.
Is it right way to handle such case?

```
model Person {
    id       String @id @default(cuid())
    name     String

    gender   Gender 

    spouseId String? @unique
    husband  Person? @relation("Spouse", fields: [spouseId], references: [id])
    wife     Person? @relation("Spouse")
}
```

It is not convenient to get spouse of the person, I need to check manually gender and only then check what I have inside wife or husband fields.

Does it possible to have only one property with spouse?

But if my model is good enough please help me to find return type of this function which saves spouse in special property.

```
async function getPerson({
  id,
  userId,
}: Pick<Person, "id"> & {
  userId: User["id"];
}): WhatIsTypeHere? {
  const person = await prisma.person.findFirst({
    where: { id, userId },
    include: { wife: true, husband: true },
  });


    return person?.spouseId
    ? {
        ...people,
        spouse: person.gender === Gender.MALE ? person.wife : person.husband,
      }
    : person;
}
```

I tried with 2 different properties